# My script needs to run two loops at the same time to read IO data from two different sources. Is my threading correct?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

```
import threading
import mynetworking

def FirstNIC():

    for addr in mynetworking.first.scan():
        print addr

def SecondNIC():

    for addr in mynetworking.second.scan():
        print addr

first  = threading.Thread(target=FirstNIC)
second = threading.Thread(target=SecondNIC)

first.start()
second.start()
```

That's the basic code structure I intend to you. The program will be running two `while True` loops to read data coming in over two different network sources. The script above needs to collect that data and log it.

Will this code work? Is it any good? Should the threads return the `addr` for the main program to log? Or should I simply replace `print addr` with `log(addr)`?

This is my first time with multithreading so I'm not entirely sure how this works...

Comment: Will the scan method return, or is it a generator (uses yield)?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine except that your print statments can collide because they could both write at once.  Use `Queue.queue` for easy synchronization:

```
import threading
import mynetworking
import Queue

def FirstNIC(queue):
    for addr in mynetworking.first.scan(queue):
        queue.put(addr)

def SecondNIC(queue):
    for addr in mynetworking.second.scan():
        queue.put(addr)

def logger(queue):
    while True:
        print queue.get()

output_queue = Queue.queue()
first  = threading.Thread(target=FirstNIC, args=(output_queue,))
second = threading.Thread(target=SecondNIC, args=(output_queue,))

first.start()
second.start()

logger(output_queue)
```

Comment: I'll read up on Queue now. Thanks. One more thing, I've read that threads don't handle KeyboardInterrupt exceptions properly. How would I cleanly, exit that program?

Comment: see Threading.Thread.daemon.  If you set daemon to True on your threads, they will exit when the main thread exits.  In the logging function you may want to call `queue.empty()`, so you don't end up blocking forever on `queue.get()`.  Then you could check for exit conditions.  Or you could put the logger in its own thread (making sure to set daemon=True) and check for exit conditions in the main thread.